# Go back arrow and kebab menu not showing up in Gmail app in gmail addon

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-addons

I am developing a sample addon. The add-on is working fine on desktop gmail but in android mobile gmail app, when i open my add-on, i notice that "Go back arrow" and "**[kebab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AqBl6.png)**" menu is not showing up. Although both of these are showing and working fine on desktop gmail.com.

[First image is when I open gmail on desktop and can see the go back and kebab menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AqBl6.png)
[Second image is when I open gmail app on mobiel and can not see the go back and kebab menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qmeGg.png)
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, I am reviewing your post. Your question is okay, but you could add some code, to help the community help you. It is also better to upload an image directly, since link addresses may change over time.

Comment: @rainer, I do not have code for these as code for these is controlled by Google, we do not code for kebab menu or go back arrow button.